# I want to convert array of hash to single hash with specific format in ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-hash

I have a `hash` called **hash1**

```
hash1 = [{key: 'key1', value: 'value1'}, {key: 'key2', value: 'value2'}, {key: 'key3', value: 'value3'}]
```

And want to convert to below format

```
{'key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2', 'key3' => 'value3'}
```

Comment: BTW, `hash1` is a misleading variable name, because it is an array, not a hash. If you want to have "hash" in the name, use the plural: `hashes`

Comment: Presumably, the values of `:key` are unique, as you have not said what is wanted when, say, `hash1 = [{key: "key", value: 'value1'}, {key: "key", value: 'value2'}]`.

Comment: Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages, "[mcve]" and "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)". We'd like to see evidence of your effort. What did you try? Did you search and not find anything? Did you find stuff but it didn't help? Did you try writing code? If not, why? If so, what is the smallest code example that shows what you tried and why didn't it work? Without that it looks like you didn't try and want us to write it for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the nested hashes in `hash1` always have exactly a `:key` and a `:value` key in that order, you can convert their [`values`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Hash.html#method-i-values) to a hash via [`Array#to_h`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-to_h):

```
hash1.map(&:values).to_h
#=> {"key1"=>"value1", "key2"=>"value2", "key3"=>"value3"}
```

But I'd rather be a little more explicit:

```
hash1.map { |h| h.values_at(:key, :value) }.to_h
#=> {"key1"=>"value1", "key2"=>"value2", "key3"=>"value3"}
```

Comment: ...or `hash1.each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h[g[:key]] = g[:value] }`.